# Problemas con Jquery y validación de formulario

Tags: javascript, jquery, formularios

Estaba trabajando en un formulario con JavaScript y funcionaba perfecto. 
Quise introducir Jquery para limpiar un poco el código y que quede más fácil de mantener. Pero cuando lo transcribo (en parte) a Jquery, no funciona. 
Adjunto el código en JavaScript.

```
const nombre = document.getElementById("nombre");
const email = document.getElementById("email");
const mensaje = document.getElementById("mensaje");
const emailInvalido = email.validity;
const textAreaChequeada = mensaje.validity;

function validarForm() {
    nombre.addEventListener("input", validarNombre);
    email.addEventListener("input", validarEmail);
    mensaje.addEventListener("input", validarMensaje);
    validarNombre();
    validarEmail();
    validarMensaje();
  }

  function validarNombre() {
    if (nombre.value == "") {
      nombre.setCustomValidity("Por favor ingrese su nombre");
      nombre.style.borderColor = "#E22E11";
    } else {
      nombre.setCustomValidity("");
      nombre.style.borderColor = "#3D8B44";
    }
  }

  function validarEmail() {
    if (email.value == "") {
      email.setCustomValidity("Por favor ingrese su E-mail");
      email.style.borderColor = "#E22E11";
    } else if (emailInvalido.patternMismatch) {
      email.setCustomValidity("Por favor ingrese un E-mail valido");
      email.style.borderColor = "#E22E11";
    } else {
      email.style.borderColor = "#39A858";
      email.setCustomValidity("");
    }
  }

  function validarMensaje() {
    if (nombre.value == "") {
      mensaje.setCustomValidity("Por favor escriba su mensaje");
      mensaje.style.borderColor = "#E22E11";
    } else if (mensaje.value.trim() !== "") {
      mensaje.setCustomValidity("");
      mensaje.style.borderColor = "#3D8B44";
    } else if (textAreaChequeada.valueMissing) {
      mensaje.setCustomValidity("Por favor detalle como podríamos ayudarlo");
      mensaje.style.borderColor = "#E22E11";
    }
  }
window.addEventListener("load", validarForm);
```

Ahora simplemente quiero transcribir los selectores a Jquery y que se ejecute lo mismo. 
Adjunto codigo con Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

const nombre = $("#nombre");
  const email = $("#email");
  const mensaje = $("#mensaje");
const emailInvalido = email.validity;
const textAreaChequeada = mensaje.validity;

function validarForm() {
    nombre.addEventListener("input", validarNombre);
    email.addEventListener("input", validarEmail);
    mensaje.addEventListener("input", validarMensaje);
    validarNombre();
    validarEmail();
    validarMensaje();
  }

  function validarNombre() {
    if (nombre.value == "") {
      nombre.setCustomValidity("Por favor ingrese su nombre");
      nombre.style.borderColor = "#E22E11";
    } else {
      nombre.setCustomValidity("");
      nombre.style.borderColor = "#3D8B44";
    }
  }

  function validarEmail() {
    if (email.value == "") {
      email.setCustomValidity("Por favor ingrese su E-mail");
      email.style.borderColor = "#E22E11";
    } else if (emailInvalido.patternMismatch) {
      email.setCustomValidity("Por favor ingrese un E-mail valido");
      email.style.borderColor = "#E22E11";
    } else {
      email.style.borderColor = "#39A858";
      email.setCustomValidity("");
    }
  }

  function validarMensaje() {
    if (nombre.value == "") {
      mensaje.setCustomValidity("Por favor escriba su mensaje");
      mensaje.style.borderColor = "#E22E11";
    } else if (mensaje.value.trim() !== "") {
      mensaje.setCustomValidity("");
      mensaje.style.borderColor = "#3D8B44";
    } else if (textAreaChequeada.valueMissing) {
      mensaje.setCustomValidity("Por favor detalle como podríamos ayudarlo");
      mensaje.style.borderColor = "#E22E11";
    }
  }

  validarForm();
});
```

Lo único que estoy cambiando son los selectores en la parte de arriba y en vez de poner un **event listener**  cuando la ventana esté cargada, estoy poniendo en Jquery el método **.ready()** y al final llamo a la función validarForm() para que ejecute el código. 
Alguna idea donde puede estar el error? 
Ya he chequeado y Jquery está funcionando correctamente en la página.

Comment: No son lo mismo los `DOM elements` que los `jQuery elements` tienen métodos diferentes.El `style` y los eventos los tendrías que hacer de manera distinta (como se hace en jquery) si vas a usar esos selectores.

Comment: @x3kagainstSEbehavior Ah!! Que detalle! jaja. No sabia eso. Muchas gracias!! :D

Comment: [jquery object and dom element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974582/jquery-object-and-dom-element). Podrías acceder directamente al DOM element desde el selector de jquery haciendo `$("#nombre")[0];` Pero si lo que quieres es cambiar el código para pasarlo a `jquery` lo mas normal es que uses los métodos de `jquery`